# Show sonarqube analysis result of Multi module gradle projects under root project

Tags: sonarqube, build.gradle, multi-module

I have a multimodule java grade project. I followed  https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/ and was  able to configure sonarqube project for them.

But in the analysis it shows the analysis result of each project separately.

Is there a way I can show the analysis under root project. And on clicking on the root project it should show the details of subprojects.

My issue is that I have 3 root projects and each root project has alt least 5 subprojects and the sonar analysis pages looks crowded.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I moved the apply plugin: “org.sonarqube” from subprojects to outside and it worked fine